# How to stop false DMCA causing URLs to delist?

Tags: copyright, negative-seo, dmca

Recently a malicious actor started to attack the URLs of my website by using DMCA reports. I did not notice the first report so it caused me to delist some of the most important URLs of the website from Google search.

But the attacker did not stop there. Another report with the same false evidence was sent after about two weeks and I had the third DMCA yesterday. I'm counter noticing Google about each report, but is there any way to stop the guy from trying to delist URLs or some way I can tell Google about this?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to directly communicate to Google that you're a victim of fraudulent DMCA takedown requests, but Google does state under [Infringement Notification](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/legal-removal-request?complaint_type=dmca): “Misrepresentations made in your notice…may expose you to liability for damages…[of more than] $100,000 in costs and attorneys fees…” You could hire an attorney to send the filer a _cease and desist_, and forward that to Google's Legal department - perhaps that might trigger something internally.

Comment: I agree with @dan

Comment: Not everyone can afford a lawyer and the cost may outweigh the benefit, so hopefully there are other ways to handle this that users here can suggest.

Comment: It seems like they have an insider in Google who helps them to delist the rejected URLs from delisting. It's an obvious violation of laws happening from the Google side. So can anyone help us reach Google or tell the story somehow?

Comment: @Cardia I have bad news for you. It is not an obvious violation of laws from Google side, and as law stands it is safer to follow malicious and invalid DMCA. Even the malicious DMCA filer would be hard to prosecute. As laws stand no, in practice, there is no easy way to stop this. Yes, you run in one of clear cases how DMCA is broken and easy to abuse. You can try to contact USA lawmakers though obviously it is unlikely to result in direct fixes.

Answer (score 1):

### You can not stop this

To file a counter-notice, you can send the required information to Google using the
[DMCA counter notification form](https://support.google.com/legal/contact/lr_counternotice)

[Transparency Report](https://transparencyreport.google.com) provides data on the requests from copyright owners and governments to remove information from Google products.

Comment: They did not respond or take any action after 10 business days. I filed another counter-notice which I hope could bring those URLs back but it has not happened yet.